# google map api fails in script but works in browser

Tags: php, wordpress, google-maps

I have used following code in php to get dstoffset and timeoffset.

```
  $fullurl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?location=";
  $fullurl.=rawurlencode($lats).",".rawurlencode($longs);
  $fullurl.="&amp;timestamp=".rawurlencode($timestamp);
  $fullurl.="&amp;sensor=false&amp;key=$mykey"; 
  preg_replace('/[ \t]+/', ' ', preg_replace('/\s*$^\s*/m', "\n", $fullurl));
   try
 {
   $resultStr = file_get_contents($fullurl); // get json content 
 }
 catch (Exception $e)
 {

   echo " Please make sure you are online.";
   exit;
 }
```

It was working alright earlier.
Client has recently updated core packages to wordpress 4.2.2
Now script is getting invalid request error.
I have copied generated url from the page and pasted in browser.
And it is working alright there.
Can someone please point out what could be wrong and how can i fix
that.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Earlier i used to have whold $fullurl in one line.But url displayed in browser page seems to have a line break at /json? and that has prompted me to 
break line into parts.

Comment: Please post error as well

Comment: the `preg_replace`-part makes no  sense to me. `$fullurl` will not be modified and even when it would the result would be an invalid url because of unencoded whitespaces.

Comment: @Dr.Molle what i had believed was using preg i would be able to remove any newline or whitespace in the url generated.Yeah it could be counter productive and i have removed it .

Comment: @AkshayHegde there is no error message.
As i mentioned in php script $resultstr  get invalid request , Where as same url used in browser is getting proper data.If there is any issue with url, authentication or any thing else why would browser fetch data and script will fail.

Answer (score 0):

replace the `&amp;` 's with `&`  . A browser will "decode" the `&amp;` automatically , but your script will send it as it is

The result will be that the names of the submitted variables are:

- `location`
- `amp;timestamp`
- `amp;sensor`
- `amp;key`